# How to see where a Java array is in memory

Tags: java, memory

I was wondering whether it was possible to see where in system memory a particular Java array has been allocated. What I mean is, given the following code:

```
public class TestArray {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] my_array = new int[]{5,6,7,8,9};
    while(true) {
      //do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

how can I see where my_array is allocated in system memory? Or even just on the JVM heap. What tools do I need to be using to get this info?

Comment: [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) is a good place to start.

Comment: VisualVM doesn't really tell me anything about the location of memory though..

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "where"? Virtual memory manager is a tricky thing. Even if you have an actual pointer to a memory location, that pointer is only good in the context of the process that generated it. Outside of it, it's just a meaningless number.

Comment: well, what I'm interested in is seeing how the array elements are stored, is it a contiguous block of memory, or is it in many different places.. Is there some way to determine this in a single running application?

Comment: 1. pass array to jni method 2. set breakpoint in gdb. Still not sure why you'd want that information...